# MVC3 Razor: Is it Possible to Render a Legacy ASCX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, ascx

With the Razor view engine in MVC3,

> Is it possible to render a legacy ascx?

---

I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Footer.ascx")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Try this instead:

```
@Html.Partial("Footer")
```

or

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Footer"); }
```

Comment: Also, change the control's code-behind so it inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl instead of System.Web.UI.UserControl

Comment: thanks for saving me :) @Webdeveloper: you mentioned important point, without that it was throwing exception.

Comment: I had to add the extension for this to work for me `@Html.Partial("Footer.ascx")` (with MVC4)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that I haven't seen a lot of people posting this solution:

```
Html.RenderAction("Footer", "Home");
```

This is better practise if you are using MVC, because you can specify any data you need in the controller instead of trying to manage it in a free-floating partial view.  Very beneficial if you use a BaseController class to initialize all your calls.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    // ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Footer() {
         // do work
        return PartialView();
    }

    // ...
}
```