# NavigateURL in MVC has extra domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have an **asp.net MenuItem** user control created ( [similar to what this post has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934319/use-a-legacy-asp-net-ascx-user-control-in-mvc-razor-view/33275364#33275364) ) within inside a MVC view. The user control works as expected, except the NavigateUrl.

This is the menuitem inside the usercontrol.

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="View Account" NavigateUrl="~/pages/account.aspx" />
```

The link looks fine if the user control is being rendered from a webform, it shows

```
http://localhost/SampleTest/pages/account.aspx
```

However, put the usercontrol inside the mvc view will have it rendered as

```
http://localhost/SampleTest/SampleTest/pages/account.aspx
```

There's an extra domain name "SampleTest" in the url.

What should I do to get rid of the extra domain name?

Comment: hey ct is it a MVC View?

Comment: @Bharat yeah it's a MVC view.  Let me know if you need all the code. But the structure is kinda similar to the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your URL navigation to URL.content.

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="View Account" NavigateUrl="@URL.content("~/pages/account.aspx")" />
```

code is not tested, but you can do like these.