# Render the same user control multiple times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, ascx

Is it possible to render the same User Control (.ASCX) multiple times? The idea is to create dashboard with widgets that are represented as User Controls. There can be several Widgets that differ with their settings only.

MVC View:

```
@Html.Partial("ReportViewerUserControl", 1)
@Html.Partial("ReportViewerUserControl", 2)
```

User control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Int32>" %>
<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ /* */ }   
</script>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Now only one user control is displayed on the page and Chrome's console alerts of 2 identical errors:

```
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type 'Sys._Application'.
Parameter name: instance
```

Comment: You cannot use UserControls from asp.net in asp.net mvc view. It will not work.

Comment: You can create partial views instead of a user control and those can be rendered as many times as you like.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov - not true , you should really read up on mvc framework a little more , you'll see the advantages of partial views over legacy ascx controls, but if you must it can be done

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538869/mvc3-razor-is-it-possible-to-render-a-legacy-ascx

Comment: I CAN render 1 user control, there is no problem with it. The problem is to render several identical user controls

Comment: Still waiting for an answer